# Crash of my command line tool when it tries to access some Console Cursor related properties

Tags: .net, command-line, crash, console

I'm trying to retrieve the standard output from a little command line tool that I wrote (in .NET too) by starting a process with it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517830/how-to-catch-a-standard-output-from-my-command-line).

It works perfectly except if my command line tool tries to retrieve the `Console.CursorTop` property, or tries to set the `Console.CursorVisible` property. In those cases, it crashes.

I don't understand why this is happening, other methods or properties of `Console` 
might work but some like theses don't. Is there some kind of hidden `Cursor` object in `Console` that never get initialized if started that way?

This tool works fine if I launch it from the explorer or if I run it in a cmd.

Could someone explain me why it happens and how I can prevent it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that problem is in Console.CursorTop or CursorVisible properties? Have you tried isolating your problem to simple console application? This sample (http://ideone.com/MHi07K) seem to run without problems on local machine.

Comment: You cannot refer to cursor properties when you forced the console mode app to run without a console, ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow property.  There is no cursor.  Nor would you *want* to tinker with it, redirection cannot in any way deal with placement of text.  Use the IsOutputRedirected helper function in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453272/17034) to avoid the crash and to make your output compatible with redirection.