# ASP.NET equivalent to Python's os.system([string])

Tags: python, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2012

I have an app made in Python, which accesses a Linux server's command prompt with  `os.system([string])`

Now I'd like to transfer this away from Python, into some language like ASP.NET or something.

Is there a way to access the server's command prompt and run commands with ASP.NET or any technology found in Visual Studio?

This needs to run in a web app, where a user will click a button, and then a server-side command will run, so it's important that the technology suggested is compatible with all that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247668/running-command-line-from-an-aspx-page-and-returning-output-to-page

Comment: I added a complete ASPx example of calling a Process and setting it's output to an ASP element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it isn't ASP.net specific but in c#:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start([string]);
```

Or With more access to the specific parts of running a program (like arguments, and output streams)

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c dir *.cs";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
```

here is how you could combine this with an ASPx Page:

First Process.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Process.aspx.cs" Inherits="com.gnld.web.promote.Process" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Process</title>
    <style>
        textarea { width: 100%; height: 600px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="RunCommand" runat="server" Text="Run Dir" onclick="RunCommand_Click" />
      <h1>Output</h1>
      <asp:TextBox ID="CommandOutput" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" TextMode="MultiLine" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the code behind:

```
using System;

namespace com.gnld.web.promote
{
    public partial class Process : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void RunCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/c dir *.*",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                }
            })
            {
                cmd.Start();
                CommandOutput.Text = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This whole thing is uncharted waters for me, but is there a way I can run this C# code in a web application? As in, a user clicks something, then this code is triggered.

Comment: In a web application this code would be attached to the code behind in the Page_Load() function if you wanted accessing the page to trigger this code or in an "_OnClick()" event if you wanted to trigger it when clicking on an `<ASP:Button>`

Comment: Okay, I'll take you word for it. Thanks. By the way, got any newbie tutorials that would help me get familiar with asp.net and c# scripts? I'll research as well, but I thought I'd ask.